# How can I sum values if two fields are the same using JSON COUNT - SUM

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

this is my JSON file.

```
{"result":[
{"beer":"23","store":"1","table":"1"},
{"beer":"12","store":"1","table":"1"},
{"beer":"5","store":"1","table":"2"}]}
```

I want to sum beer if the store and table fields are the same.

The result should be be 2 records:

```
beer 35, store 1 table 1
beer 5, store 1 table 2
```

This is the MYSQL Query I use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data  ORDER BY beer DESC";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = array();

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
            array_push($result, array('beer' => $row[1],
                                      'store'  => $row[2],
                                      'table' => $row[3]));

        echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

Comment: Please make your title lower case

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @rene: `JSON` is uppercased by design and the sql keywords are conventionally uppercased as well. So it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @zerkms I have a different view on that...

Comment: @rene: even though you do - you have left the original capitalization for the original words. Which means that your "different" view perfectly matches to mine ;-D

Answer (score 2):

Hope you need `group by`

```
$sql = "
    SELECT sum(beer) as beer, store, table 
    FROM data 
    GROUP BY store, table  
    ORDER BY beer DESC
";
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this directly from the sql:

$query = "SELECT sum(beer) as beer, store, table 
    FROM data 
    GROUP BY store, table " ;

to sum it from the json:

```
$json_result = json_decode($json_var) ;

$result = array() ;

foreach($json_result->result as $key=>$value){
    if(!isset($result[$value->store])){
        $result[$value->store] = array() ;
        $result[$value->store][$value->table] = $value->beer ;
    }
    else if(!isset($result[$value->store][$value->table])){
        $result[$value->store][$value->table] = $value->beer ;
    }
    else{
        $result[$value->store][$value->table] += $value->beer ;
    }
}

$result will contain the json sum
```